# Good way to show "Toast" in AsyncBackground

Tags: android, android-networking, retrofit

When establishing a connection, sometimes an error might occur or the wifi might be turned off. So in these cases I would like to show a Toast message to the user.

So I tried something like this:

```
protected String doInBackground (String ... args) {
    QircAccount account = new MyAccount(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        acceptable = MyManager.INSTANCE.getService().getAcceptable(account.getUsername(), account.getAuthToken(), recId);
    }
    catch (RetrofitError re) {
        Response r = re.getResponse();
        if (r!=null && r.getStatus() == 403) {
            isLoggedIn = false;
        }
        if (re.isNetworkError()) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connectivity problem.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

But this gives an error like:

```
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

**Questions**

- So its best to show Toast message in `onPostExecute`?
- How should I pass the message "connectivity problem" to `onPostExecute`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always do

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       Toast.makeText(.....).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think that'll be best for me right now as I have lot of activities with Toast in `doInBackground`

Comment: @birdy Don't do this. You are just asking for trouble. `AsyncTask` has methods to update the `UI`. Use `onProgressUpdate()` if you still have work to do and if not then use `onPostExecute()`

Comment: @codeMagic Which troubles though?

Comment: Alex, I know the solution can work but my problem with it is that it introduces another element that can cause problems if used wrong (which I've seen quite often). If used properly, yeah it works, but it is much less complicated to just use the built-in methods that `AsyncTask` provides, IMHO.

Comment: @codeMagic I can't follow, what you've seen quite often?

Comment: I've seen people use that in `doInBackground()` a lot and screw it up and make more trouble for themselves. So, I just see no point in adding an extra element when the class already has built-in methods for this exact situation.

Comment: @codeMagic I've seen even more people using the approach I've suggested and being happy with it. I think this argument is as strong as yours.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I don't have any exact examples (just from memory). I'm not going to argue about to use it or not. I would just suggest not to. As I've said, it is just introducing another piece to screw up. I just don't see why people don't just suggest to use the methods that are there. Otherwise, why even use `AsyncTask`...just use a plain old `Thread` to do the background work.

Answer (score 0):

```
So its best to show Toast message in onPostExecute?
```

Yes that is because `onPostExecute` run in the UI thread.

Never call `Toast.makeText` in a different Thread, only a Thread that create it will the only the one that can call/update it. hence you can still call/update from a different thread by calling the UI thread `runOnUiThread`.

```
How should I pass the message "connectivity problem" to onPostExecute?
```

just return it as a String in the `doInBackground` since it returns as a string.

```
if (re.isNetworkError()) {
        return "Connectivity problem.";
   }
```

in `onPostExecute`

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: don't I need to check the string in `onPostExecute` to see whether it reads "connectivity problem"? Or else in every onPostExecute the user will see a Toast...even if the operation was successful.

Comment: @birdy then dont return it, just call it by calling the UI thread